# What am I Doing Wrong Here(Java) Decimal to Binary

Tags: java, binary, decimal

This is the code I have written:
For example,

```
1.) Input =12
2.) No. of Digits = 2
3.) 00 (this is it: Expected Result 1100)
```

It prints half the binary, but I don't really know where the other half goes.

```
    import java.util.Scanner;
    class Decimal_to_Binary
    {
        public static void main(String args[])
        {
            Scanner Prakhar=new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Enter a Number");
            int x=Prakhar.nextInt();
            int z=x;
            int n=(int)Math.floor(Math.log10(x) +1);
            System.out.println("No. of Digits="+n);
            int a[]=new int[n];
            int b=0;
            int j=0;
            while (x!=0)
            {
                x=z%2;
                a[j]=x;
                j++;
                z=z/2;
            }
            int l=a.length;
            for(int i=0;i<l;i++)
            {
                System.out.print(a[i]);
            }
        }
    }
```

P.S. I know there are other methods to do it, so please don't suggest using another method.

Comment: "Prints half the binary" is not a very good description.  Show your input and results!!

Comment: What is ur expected output

Comment: The loop condition is wrong, or the `x=z%2` is. You'll end up only calculating it once as: 12%2=0 - - Also, the length of the array is going to give you array index issues. Currently it will be 3 in length, but the binary number for 12 has 4 bits.

Comment: Its not printing wrong value,u have initialised 2 size array and set only index 0 value as '0'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few problems in your code  :

1) The way number of digits in binary (n) is calculated (it should be ceil(Math.log2(number)). Since Math.log2 is not available in java we compute Math.log10(number)/ Math.log10(2)

2)  The condition check while(x!=0) it should be while(z!= 0) as you are diving z by 2 in each loop

3) Print the list in reverse to print correct binary representation.

Below is the corrected code :

```
public static void main(String args[])
 {
     Scanner Prakhar=new Scanner(System.in);
     System.out.println("Enter a Number");
     int x=Prakhar.nextInt();
     int z=x;

     // correct logic for computing number of digits
     int n=(int)Math.ceil(Math.log10(x)/Math.log10(2));

     System.out.println("No. of Digits="+n);
     int a[]=new int[n];
     int b=0;
     int j=0;
     while (z!=0)  // check if z != 0
     {
         x=z%2;
         System.out.println(x);
         a[j]=x;
         j++;
         z=z/2;
     }
     int l=a.length;

     //reverse print for printing correct binary number
     for(int i=l-1;i>=0;--i)
     {
         System.out.print(a[i]);
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually the loop checking condition that you are using inside While loop is wrong.

```
while (x!=0)    
{
       x=z%2;     --> Here x is 0 in case of even number and 1 in case of odd 
       a[j]=x;
       j++;
       z=z/2;
}
```

Here x is 0 in case of even number and 1 in case of odd (See first line inside While loop)
so in case of your example you use 12, so for first and second iteration the x is calculated as 0 so this will print and after second iteration x become 1 so while loop break.

Use following While condition -

```
 while (z!=0)    
    {
           x=z%2;     
           a[j]=x;
           j++;
           z=z/2;
    }
```